# method and classes available only for a flavour

Tags: android, android-flavors, android-flavordimension

Say I have flavour free / paid.

I want to call a method `checkSubscription()` for a paid feature. The classes referred inside that method will only be available for paid flavour, because I have put them in a different module, that compiles only for flavour paid.

Is above thing possible?, because when I'll run free flavour app, this should not give **`classNotFoundException`**. Please guide me.

**Edit**

Yes I am aware that I can check my flavour programmatically in Java like

```
if (BuildConfig.BUILD_VARIANT.equals("Your flavor name")){
   //do something
}
```

or by defining a **`buildConfigField`**.

**I explain better**

- My class `Example.java` is in module **PaidLibrary**, and **PaidLibrary** is only compiled for the **paid flavour**.
- Now I have a class `ActivityExample.java`, in which I have imported `Example.class`.
- I check current flavour before using this `Example.java`, but will this create `classNotFoundException` because `ActivityExample.java` contains import and use of `Example.java`.
- So this is my question that how to code for classes which are available for paid flavour?

Comment: I am not sure, if you are trying to find if an installed flavor is paid or free? if yes, you can create a buildConfigField in your build.gradle as a parameter in your flavor definition and retrive them and check it at runtime...

Comment: It is just an example, I have not flavour paid or free, also I can know current flavour, but that is not related to my question.

Comment: I thought may be at runtime you find your flavor and decide if you have to call the checksubscription method or not... also for your need you can use Java reflection... where you can create a module and not add it as dependency.. but get the relative path to your Java class and using method name you can invoke it.. do you need an example to proceed?

Comment: Alternative solution is by creating the same class `ActivityExample.java` inside both your flavors package directory. The class in `free` flavor must not contains `Example.class`.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך Yes, that can be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

try using reflection:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = YOUR_CLASS.class.getClassLoader();
Class specificClass = classLoader.loadClass("YOUR_CLASS_RELATIVE_PATH");
Object result;  //This is object as your method can return any datatype

Method method = specificClass.getMethod(methodName, ARGS_TO_YOUR_METHOD_IF_ANY.class); // if your arg is a custom class 
result = method.invoke(specificClass.newInstance(), ARGS_TO_YOUR_METHOD_IF_ANY)
```

Comment: I can not use this. That are not just classes, that are live instances, when app run in paid flavour. So I need to interact with that classes instances.

Comment: Ok, go ahead and try this.. if this is helpful, try up voting this answer and if it really worked don't forget to accept this answers..

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, you have to provide `Example.java` or the activity that is using `Example.java` for both paid and free flavors of your app. When you generate build with free flavor, it will not be able resolve `Example.java`, leading to compile time error. You can just add a mock/dummy/placeholder `Example.java` for your free flavor to resolve build conflicts.

Comment: People have provided solution, and you are saying not possible. :D

Comment: lol, these are just alternative workarounds, not solution to your exact problem

Comment: Does it matter, solution should not be alternative. Just our purpose should be resolved anyhow. :)